# If we have mysql in wampserver then should we need separate mysqlserver installation for (databases in) jsp development on PC

Tags: mysql, jsp, mysql-workbench

I needed to develop some jsp pages which need to connect to mysql databases. i downloaded and installed mysql community server5.5.54 but then found in my PC that i have already mysql in wamp. Was mysql of wamp enough for me or i need to install mysql server separately for my jsp developments

[image: mysqlserver usage vs. mysql in wamp]

Answer (score 0):

The WAMP server should be just fine as long as it contains a rather recent version of MySQL (5.5+). Important for MySQL Workbench is that the server must be registered as a service in Windows (as this is how WB identifiers the MySQL servers on a box).